# Turn off autoescaping in template.render

Tags: python, django, django-1.10

In Django < 1.8 there was possibility to render template without autoescaping:

```
context = Context({...}, autoescape=False)
result = template.render(context)
```

In Django 1.8/1.9 I get following deprecation waring:

```
RemovedInDjango110Warning: render() must be called with a dict, not a Context.
```

Of course I can change the `Context` instance to dict:

```
result = template.render({...})
```

But how can I force the `render` function to turn off autoescape without using `{% autoescape %}` tags in each email template (not every template in my project!)?

Only one solution comes to my mind: iterate over all context (dictionary) items and mark-them-safe (`mark_safe`), but it doesn't seem elegant.

Answer (score 3):

An `autoescape` option has been added to the Django template backend in [ticket 25469](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25469). The change will be included in the upcoming Django 1.10.

Note that you may have to enable two instances of the Django template backend in your `TEMPLATES` setting, one that enables auto escaping, and one that does not (see [this comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25469#comment:11) from the ticket. You can then choose the correct template backend depending on whether or not you want autoescape to be enabled.

Until Django 1.10 is release, note that passing a `Context` to `render()` is only deprecated in Django 1.8. It still works in Django 1.8 and 1.9.